# Accidentally deleted .xcodeproj file how to recreate it?

Tags: xcode

I did a silly mistake and deleted .xcodeproj file from command line. Since it's deleted from command line it's not in bin so it's gone. I've all other files in the project. Is there any way to recreate .xcodeproj file and fix the project?

I'm using local git provided by xCode as default, not sure if it will help?

Comment: try `git stash` . or undo all changes option from xcode.

Comment: This puts back a default initial project.

Comment: Thats mean you never had committed your code. For what you made git repository? Well if you wanted back to your inconsistent state then do `git stash pop`. It will undo `git stash` so that you have your code back. Now do experient after taking backup in your system.

Comment: I did backup before running git stash so I do have all the files. The good thing is that I got the .xcodeproj file from this command and added all the files and manage to recover the project. Struggling with .plist file.

Comment: You can create new project with same name and drag and drop the `info.plist` file and you can add tags or privacy descriptions for using Apple API's. I think that should work for you in more ease way.

Comment: Yes, got it working now. Tx for help.

Comment: As you said, `xcodeproj` is back in your project, make sure it is proper state. Once every thing fine make a good habbit of doing multiple commits in a day.

Comment: Yes learned lesson, will never forget it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't committed the deletion of the file, do the following:

1. Open **Terminal**
2. `cd /path/to/my/local/repo`
3. `git checkout -- myproject.xcodeproj`